# How to handle image aspect ratio in mobile

Tags: html, css

I got problem to handle image ratio. It become like this image:

[image: image1]

But when I adjust image size it become like this:

[image: image2]

How to handle it?

```css
.itemBox {
    height: 195px;
    margin: 15px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background-color: #e4b972; 
}
.item_img {
    width: 120px;
    height: 195px;
}
```

```html
<div class="itemBox">
<div style="float:left;">
 <img class="item_img" src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/no-image-available-icon-flat-vector-no-image-available-icon-flat-vector-illustration-132482953.jpg"  />
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Set `width: auto; height: 100%;`?

Comment: you have to use width:100%;height:auto;

Comment: it still same whe I using `width: auto;` or `width: 100%`

Comment: `width: auto;` and `height: 195px;` solves the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the size and width in the div and contain your image in the div

```css
.itemBox {
    height: 195px;
    margin: 15px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background-color: #e4b972; 
}

.div-for-img {
  width: 120px;
    height: 195px;
    float: left;
}

.item_img {
  height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="itemBox">
    <div class="div-for-img">
     <img class="item_img" src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/no-image-available-icon-flat-vector-no-image-available-icon-flat-vector-illustration-132482953.jpg"  />
    </div>
</div>
```